# Given a prime ideal $P$ in a valuation ring $A$, there is a valuation ring $B$ containing $A$ such that $B/PB$ is the fraction field of $A/P$ ?

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, local-rings, integral-extensions

Let $(A,\mathfrak m)$ be a valuation ring (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring ). Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $A$. I know that $A/P$ and $A_P$ are valuation rings .

How to show that there is a valuation ring $B$ , containing $A$, with maximal ideal $PB$ and such that $B/PB$ is the fraction field of $A/P$ ?

Comment: I guess the question wants to find a valution ring which is not Quot(A) and that the fraction field of $B/PB$ and that of $A/P$ agree. I believe one can take $B = A_P$ and use the fact that localization commutes with quotient. However, if you insist $B/PB$ to be the fraction field of $A/P$, then $P = 0$ is necessary.